# Trouble extracting xml property from ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, sharepoint

I'm using SharePoint on Premises 2019 and I have an ajax request to a SharePoint list. The list has a preexisting column named attachments which contains images that were uploaded to it.

Now the ajax request to return elements of the list returns a xml response for the attachments column. The response

```
<feed
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>e3a2717c-932c-43a0-b1c6-f81a75329948</id>
    <title />
    <updated>2024-03-26T06:02:30Z</updated>
    <entry>
        <id>http://po/sites/pssm/_api/Web/Lists(guid'f80db476-8b0c-4a8b-b9b6-0516028525d5')/Items(25)/AttachmentFiles('contact.webp')</id>
        <category term="SP.Attachment" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'f80db476-8b0c-4a8b-b9b6-0516028525d5')/Items(25)/AttachmentFiles('contact.webp')" />
        <title />
        <updated>2024-03-26T06:02:30Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:FileName>contact.webp</d:FileName>
                <d:FileNameAsPath m:type="SP.ResourcePath">
                    <d:DecodedUrl>contact.webp</d:DecodedUrl>
                </d:FileNameAsPath>
                <d:ServerRelativePath m:type="SP.ResourcePath">
                    <d:DecodedUrl>/sites/pssm/Lists/PoliceHomeAds/Attachments/25/contact.webp</d:DecodedUrl>
                </d:ServerRelativePath>
                <d:ServerRelativeUrl>/sites/pssm/Lists/PoliceHomeAds/Attachments/25/contact.webp</d:ServerRelativeUrl>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Here the image url can be found in the serverRelativeUrl tag of xml response.

This is my js loop statement that generates the  tag.

```
  <a" href="' + objArray[i].AttachmentFiles.__deferred.uri + '">    </a>;
```

For now I'm using anchor tag just so I can see the results returned by the statement more clearly. If I use image tag, it just shows me the browser image default icon.

Do help. How can I display image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML contains namespaces, so the most efficient way *imho* is Xpath. It allows you to use expressions to match nodes.

Namespaces in XML are URIs. Aliases/prefixes are used to make a serialized XML document smaller and more human readable. However the following 3 elements can all be read as `{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed`:

- `<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>`
- `<a:feed xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>`
- `<atom:feed xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>`

```js
fetchXML('https//...').then(
  (xmlDocument) => {
    // define a namespace resolver to map prefixes in the xpath 
    // expression to URIs matching the namespace definitions in the document
    const resolver = {
      lookupNamespaceURI: (prefix) => {
        const namespaces = {
          atom: 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' 
        };
        return namespaces[prefix] || null;
      }
    }
  
    const output = document.querySelector('#output');

    // clear output
    output.textContent = '';
    
    // append nodes
    output.append(
       // fetch from XML
      ...fetchNodes('//atom:entry/atom:id', xmlDocument, resolver).map(
        (node) => {
          // create HTML nodes
          const li = document.createElement('li');
          const a = li.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
          a.setAttribute('href', node.textContent);
          a.textContent = node.textContent;
          return li;
        }
      )
    );
  }
);

// helper function to fetch nodes/values
function fetchNodes(expression, context, resolver) {
    // evaluate expression in context with resolver
    const xpathResult = (context.ownerDocument || context).evaluate(
      expression,
      context,
      resolver,
      XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
      null
    );
    
    switch (xpathResult.resultType) {
      case XPathResult.BOOLEAN_TYPE :
        return xpathResult.booleanValue;
      case XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE :
        return xpathResult.numberValue;
      case XPathResult.STRING_TYPE :
        return xpathResult.stringValue;
      default:
        const result = [];
        // iterate result an fill array
        let node = xpathResult.iterateNext();
        while (node) {
            result.push(node);
            node = xpathResult.iterateNext();
        }
        return result;
    }
}


async function fetchXML(url) {
  return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(
    // await fetch(url)
    `<feed
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>e3a2717c-932c-43a0-b1c6-f81a75329948</id>
    <title />
    <updated>2024-03-26T06:02:30Z</updated>
    <entry>
        <id>http://po/sites/pssm/_api/Web/Lists(guid'f80db476-8b0c-4a8b-b9b6-0516028525d5')/Items(25)/AttachmentFiles('contact.webp')</id>
        <category term="SP.Attachment" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'f80db476-8b0c-4a8b-b9b6-0516028525d5')/Items(25)/AttachmentFiles('contact.webp')" />
        <title />
        <updated>2024-03-26T06:02:30Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:FileName>contact.webp</d:FileName>
                <d:FileNameAsPath m:type="SP.ResourcePath">
                    <d:DecodedUrl>contact.webp</d:DecodedUrl>
                </d:FileNameAsPath>
                <d:ServerRelativePath m:type="SP.ResourcePath">
                    <d:DecodedUrl>/sites/pssm/Lists/PoliceHomeAds/Attachments/25/contact.webp</d:DecodedUrl>
                </d:ServerRelativePath>
                <d:ServerRelativeUrl>/sites/pssm/Lists/PoliceHomeAds/Attachments/25/contact.webp</d:ServerRelativeUrl>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>`,
   'application/xml'
  );
}
```

```html
<ul id="output"></ul>
```